# Acquia Dev Desktop won't let me push changes to server

Tags: drupal, ssh, private-key, public-key, acquia

I've just edited some code in my Bartik theme and saved it locally. When I try to push my local code to the server using Acquia Dev Desktop I get a message that says: 'Bad Private Key File'

I have copied down the private key exactly as it appeared on my Acquia Cloud account in the credentials section, but the problem persists.

The desktop application gives me an option to generate my own private key, but this is different from the one that appears online on my Acquia Cloud account. In any case, generating my own private key results in 'SSH authentication failed'.

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: What operating system are you using? And when you said that you "copied down" the private key from Acquia Cloud, where did you copy it to?

Comment: Hey Aubrey, I am using OSX El Captain. I copied down the private key from my Acquia account to my desktop. However, i think I may have gotten the process backwards - do I need to create public/private key pair on my computer to connect with the Acquia server?

Comment: Well I've never used Acquia cloud, but yes, that's typically how it's done with other cloud services.  I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Github offers an excellent and straightforward guide](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/#platform-mac) for generating public/private key pairs.  Most version control systems and cloud services that use SSH do this.  One you have the key, you just copy and paste it to the server and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate public ssh key and private ssh key
2. public ssh key is for acquia cloud
3. private ssh key is for local dev desktop